# Recursive Lists

Tags: r

Consider the following code:

```
b <- list(u=5,v=12)
c <- list(w=13)
a <- list(b,c)
```

So a is really a list of lists. When I call `a$b`, or `a$c`, why is `NULL` returned? Likewise if I call `a$u`, `a$v`, or `a$w`, `NULL` is returned.

Also is there a difference between the following:

```
c(list(a=1,b=2,c=list(d=5,e=9)))
```

and

```
c(list(a=1,b=2,c=list(d=5,e=9)), recursive=T)
```

Comment: You could try `a <- list(b = b, c = c)`. You can do `a$b` and `a$c`.

Comment: You should avoid creating a list object "c" for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 4):

The `$` indexing operator indexes the lists by *name*.  If you want to get the first element from the unnamed list `a`, you need `a[[1]]`.

You can make a function that automatically adds names if they are not specified, similar to the way `data.frame` works (this version is all-or-nothing -- if *some* arguments are named, it won't name the remaining, unnamed ones).

```
nlist <- function(...) {
    L <- list(...)
    if (!is.null(names(L))) return(L)
    n <- lapply(match.call(),deparse)[-1]
    setNames(L,n)
}

b <- c <- d <- 1

nlist(b,c,d)
nlist(d=b,b=c,c=d)
```

For your second question, the answer is "yes"; did you try it ???

```
L <- list(a=1,b=2,c=list(d=5,e=9))
str(c(L)) 
## List of 3
##  $ a: num 1
##  $ b: num 2
##  $ c:List of 2
##   ..$ d: num 5
##   ..$ e: num 9
str(c(L,recursive=TRUE))
##  Named num [1:4] 1 2 5 9
##  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c.d" "c.e"
```

The first is a list including two numeric values and a list, the second has been flattened into a named numeric vector.

Comment: But it seems that they are basically the same thing except that the names are different.

Comment: no, the second one has been flattened: try `str` to look at the structure (it's always dangerous to rely on the printed representation ...)

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of the question , [we have in The R language definition document](http://www.r-project.org/)

> The form using $ applies to recursive objects such as lists and
>   pairlists. It allows only a literal character string or a symbol as
>   the index. That is, the index is not computable: for cases where you
>   need to evaluate an expression to find the index, use x[[expr]].

So you can change  your a from `a <- list(b,c)` to `a <- list(b=b,c=c)`

```
 a$b =  a[['b']]   ## expression 
$u
[1] 5

$v
[1] 12
```

For the second part of the question , you can try for example to apply the `$` operator, to see the difference.

```
> kk <- c(list(a=1,b=2,c=list(d=5,e=9)))              ## recursive objects
> hh <- c(list(a=1,b=2,c=list(d=5,e=9)), recursive=T) ## atomic objects
> kk$a
[1] 1
> hh$a
Error in hh$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

In reason we get a vector the  from ?c for hh

> If recursive = TRUE, the function recursively descends through lists
>   (and pairlists) combining all their elements into a vector.